# How to enable Geolocation on this Google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

Im wondering how to enable geolocation on this google map snippet

```
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
    placeholder="Enter a location">
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
  Place ID <span id="place-id"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

```
// This sample uses the Place Autocomplete widget to allow the user to search
// for and select a place. The sample then displays an info window containing
// the place ID and other information about the place that the user has
// selected.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 48.137260, lng: 11.574850},
    zoom: 13
  });

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      return;
    }

    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }

    // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
    marker.setPlace({
      placeId: place.place_id,
      location: place.geometry.location
    });
    marker.setVisible(true);

    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
    infowindowContent.children['place-id'].textContent = place.place_id;
    infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent =
        place.formatted_address;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/arabtornado/oc9ryva1/7/

This is a reference for Google maps geolocation but since im still very new to js i couldn't implement that code on the above code that has a search on it

https://jsfiddle.net/arabtornado/ectxdm1j/

Thanks

Comment: This site is not a free coding service, even if you are new to JS. You probably need to learn JS basics and [variables scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) + I don't see any attempt at joining the 2 snippets together in the code you posted in your question. Hint: infowindow and map variables need to be in the global scope, as in the first fiddle link you posted if you attempt to join the 2 scripts together, as they are used in the `handleLocationError` function.

Comment: Sorry about that i researched more and did it myself.. will post my answer later.

Comment: If you want to get an answer and help for your problem - the better is to add quality for you question and explain your snippet code at high level, (1) what do you want to achieve, (2) what do you do for it and (3) what goes wrong.People too busy to dig in a such mess of code or someone else problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
// This sample uses the Place Autocomplete widget to allow the user to search
// for and select a place. The sample then displays an info window containing
// the place ID and other information about the place that the user has
// selected.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    // Center on user's current location if geolocation prompt allowed
    var initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    map.setZoom(13);
  }, function(positionError) {
    // User denied geolocation prompt - default to Chicago
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(39.8097343, -98.5556199));
    map.setZoom(13);
  });

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      return;
    }

    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }

    // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
    marker.setPlace({
      placeId: place.place_id,
      location: place.geometry.location
    });
    marker.setVisible(true);

    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
    infowindowContent.children['place-id'].textContent = place.place_id;
    infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent =
        place.formatted_address;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);

     placeid = place.place_id;
  });


}
```

```
<meta name="referrer" content="never">
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">

<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
    placeholder="Enter a location">
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
  Place ID <span id="place-id"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/arabtornado/oc9ryva1/38/